# How to retrieve an value from xml for a particular node and again update the xml  

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <Image>    
        <Overview>13</Overview>  
        <Gallery1>1</Gallery1>    
        <Gallery2>4</Gallery2>
        <Gallery3>6</Gallery3>    
        <Gallery4>1</Gallery4>
     </Image>
```

This is my xml file.
I have a dropdown value with values (gallery1, gallery2, gallery3 and so on).
If user selects gallery2 and types 5 in the text box
and clicks the OK button, then I need to load my above XML file and check what gallery  value we need to update. But first we need to get the value from XML.

Here I am trying to update gallery2 so first I need get the gallery2 value (4)
then add the new value with old value (5+4=9) and then save. So now gallery2 will contain the value 9.

result

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <Image>    
        <Overview>13</Overview>  
        <Gallery1>1</Gallery1>    
        **<Gallery2>9</Gallery2>**
        <Gallery3>6</Gallery3>    
        <Gallery4>1</Gallery4>
     </Image>
```

Comment: OK, and which part of your code do you need help with? Or do you just want some general directions on which .net classes to use?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking is

```
 protected void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl = GetLabel(275, 20);
        //Declare and load new XmlDocument
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(MapPath("XmlSample.xml"));
        //delete a mode
        XmlNode node;
        node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Image");
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        //create a node and add it
        XmlElement newElement =
        xmlDoc.CreateElement("myNewElement");
        node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Image");
        node.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newElement, node);
        xmlDoc.Save(MapPath("XmlSampleModified.xml"));
    }
```

Comment: why  is this    line    code  we  are using 
("//myChild[@ChildID='ref-3']");//  what is 'ref-3'  doing  here

Comment: what is  mychild   represent here  should i  replace   this  with Image

Answer (score 0):

A more general-purpose version of this method would take the entire XPath to the element you want to change, instead of just assuming that it's a child of a top-level `Image` element.

```
private void AddElementValue(XmlDocument doc, string tagName, int valueToAdd)
{
   XmlElement elm = doc.SelectSingleElement("/Image/" + tagName);
   Debug.Assert(elm != null, "Didn't find " + tagName);
   int currentValue;
   if (int.TryParse(elm.InnerText, out currentValue))
   {
      elm.InnerText = (currentValue + valueToAdd).ToString();
      return;
   }
   Debug.Fail(elm.InnerText + " can't be parsed as an integer.");       
}
```